# How to copy files using wildcards in Unix

Tags: linux, copy, wildcard

How can I copy files to current directory (using wildcards) which names are matches following rules:

1. start with the word `file`
2. after that word have one or more numbers
3. after the numbers have `.txt` extension

I tried:

`$ cp path_name/file[0-9].txt ./`

Here are some examples of the files I want to copy:

```
file1.txt  
file45.txt  
file5642.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried `$ cp path_name/file*.txt .`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cp `find /path/to/files |  grep -E 'file[[:digit:]]+\.txt'` ./
```

(change `/path/to/files` to your actual path, change `./` to your destination directory)

Comment: I 'v already tried that...it only copies the files with only one digit after the word "file" .I mean files like "file5.txt" or "file7.txt" ..I want to copy the files with one or more numbers after the word "file"

Comment: I tried: cp path_name/file[[:digit]]*.txt ./ 
That one also copies the file with the name"file8a.txt".I don't want any other characters exept from number(s) after the word file..I also want the conclusion ".txt"

Comment: I tried: cp path_name/file[[:digit:]]*.txt ./ 
That one also copies the file " file8a.txt" ..I want to copy the files that only have number(s) and anything else exept numbers after the word "file".Those files should also end with the conclusion ".txt"

Comment: You are right, that was not 100% correct, see the updated answer in the question